# Heroku - Java WAR Deploy error during deploy with --includes context.xml file

Tags: java, xml, heroku, war, web-deployment

I'm struggling with deploying my simple Java app to Heroku. I'm deploying with WAR Deployment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment
However, my context.xml file has to be not within the WAR but included.
At first I've add the Tomcat webapp-runner options --enable-naming and --context-xml=path/to/context.xml:

```
heroku config:set WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS="--enable-naming --context-xml=path/to/context.xml"
```

where **=path/to/context.xml** is the real path to the proper context.xml
and then I use:

```
heroku war:deploy myapp.war --includes newrelic.jar:newrelic.xml
```

Where myapp.war -> is full path to the proper .war file and newrelic.xml is just name of my .xml file (context.xml) since I provided path to the context.xml in WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS. However whenever I try to deploy I've got an error like this:
Uploading ParkingBookSystem.war

```
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: park-book-app
       - including: context.xml
 ! ERROR: There was an error packaging the application for deployment.
```

What Am I doing wrong? Is there an error in my command WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS and --includes?

Comment: Are you using "newrelic.jar:newrelic.xml" int he command?

Comment: No I'm using exactly this command: heroku war:deploy C:\myapp\myapp.war --includes context.xml

Comment: Try setting the env bar HEROKU_DEBUG=1 locally and run again. Share the output